# Why is my bootstrap collapse code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I want to display a collapsed div in a cell of my table.

```
<td>
    <a class="text-decoration-none" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="{{ '#collapseMsg' ~ message.id }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{ 'collapseMsg' ~ message.id }}">
        <span class="text-dark fw-bold">{{ message.title }}</span>
    </a>
    <div class"collapse mt-2" id="{{ 'collapseMsg' ~ message.id }}">
        <div class="card card-body">
            {{ message.content }}
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

My code display the collapsed div and the button doesn't hide it, but it is supposed to be hidden by default with `.collapse` class. I included `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced local bootstrap link with the online ones:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It works properly now

Comment: When posting a question, please provide all the code related to solving it. In this case, the community will help better.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static name for id on both elements, if it works try to map them properly. I'm not sure when we use `~` for concating.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The ~ is because i am working in Twig, it is inside a Loop `foreach`

Comment: Please any other advices?